# React: Close sidebar menu on route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to close sidebar menu when the user has selected a new target URL. With react-router-dom, how can I detect when the user navigates to a new page?

```html
 <div className="" id="rightMenu">
    <div className="sidebar_link">
      <a href="#" id="personal_account"
          onClick={() =>
          this.props.history.push('/personal-account')}
               Personal Account
               </a>
    </div>
     <div
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a history listener using [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history).

If using react-router-dom v4/5/6:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

// Listen for changes to the current location.
const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
  // location is an object like window.location
  console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state);
});

// To stop listening, call the function returned from listen().
unlisten();
```

I wrap this up in an `useEffect` hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
    // logic to close sidebar
  });
    
  return () => {
    unlisten();
  }
}, []);
```

If still using a class-based component you can achieve the same by using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to add the listener, and the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method to clear it out.

```
this.unlisten = null;

componentDidMount() {
  this.unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
    // logic to close sidebar
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.unlisten();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I am using class component,  thats why Hook Call Warning appears.

Comment: @Aytac Oh, right, I totally see the `this.props` in your snippet now. You can achieve the same with `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount`. I'll update answer to add class-based component version.

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like this:

```
const [isMenuVisible, setIsMenuVisible] = useState(true)
return(
    <RightMenu className="" id="rightMenu" isVisible={isMenuVisible}>
        <div className="sidebar_link">
            <a href="#" id="personal_account"
             onClick={() => {
                  setIsMenuVisible(false)
                  this.props.history.push('/personal-account')}
            }>
             Personal Account
            </a>
       </div>
   </RightMenu>
)
const RightMenu = styled.div<{ isVisible: boolean }>`
    display: ${({ isVisible }) => isVisible?'flex':'none'};  
`
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I am using class component,  thats why Hook Call Warning appears.